# Errors while compiling Monero on openSUSE

Tags: linux, compile, source, build

I'm trying to compile latest version of Monero On openSUSE Leap, but it throws an error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target obj_common
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/monero/build/release'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/monero/build/release'
[ 45%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/base58.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/command_line.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/dns_utils.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/util.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/i18n.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/perf_timer.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/task_region.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/thread_group.cpp.o
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp: In constructor ‘tools::thread_group::data::data(std::size_t)’:
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:64:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘tools::thread_group::data::node::node(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   , stop(false) {
               ^
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:64:15: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:28:0:
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.h:114:12: note: tools::thread_group::data::node::node(tools::thread_group::data::node&&)
     struct node {
            ^
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.h:114:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘tools::thread_group::data::node&&’
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp: In member function ‘void tools::thread_group::data::dispatch(std::function<void()>)’:
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:138:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘tools::thread_group::data::node::node(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   std::unique_ptr<work> latest(new work{std::move(f), node{nullptr}});
                                                                   ^
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:138:67: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:28:0:
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.h:114:12: note: tools::thread_group::data::node::node(tools::thread_group::data::node&&)
     struct node {
            ^
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.h:114:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘tools::thread_group::data::node&&’
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:138:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘tools::thread_group::data::work::work(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   std::unique_ptr<work> latest(new work{std::move(f), node{nullptr}});
                                                                    ^
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:138:68: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.cpp:28:0:
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.h:119:12: note: tools::thread_group::data::work::work(tools::thread_group::data::work&&)
     struct work {
            ^
/home/user/monero/src/common/thread_group.h:119:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/build.make:230: recipe for target 'src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/thread_group.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/thread_group.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/monero/build/release'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:535: recipe for target 'src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/obj_common.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/monero/build/release'
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/monero/build/release'
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

It seems to be related to `src/common/thread_group.cpp`. What should I do?

**Update:**

I'm able to build the official stable release (v 0.10.0) from the source. So the problem must be related to newer commits.

Comment: FWIW, I just pulled and built fine on macOS...

Comment: Have you ever built Monero successfully on that computer or is it the first time?

Comment: @ClementJ., this is the first time.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm able to build the official stable release (v 0.10.0) from the source. So the problem must be related to newer commits.

That is indeed the case. This [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1431) should resolve the [issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1428)

Comment: That indeed resulted in some progress, but new errors emerged and I'm still unable to compile it. Please see [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1428#issuecomment-266285959).